# Executing code defined in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to be able to execute a piece of code that is defined in a string. I am aware of performSelector: but the object that will perform the selector is going to be different.

Example strings

```
[[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] hasFlash]
[UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]
```

So what I would like to do is something along the lines of

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"[[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] hasFlash]");
if (selector) {
    // Show flash buttons
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158036/eval-in-objective-c

Comment: Just think of it for a while: Isn't objective-c a compiled language? Does your phone have a compiler for this?

Let's think about this a bit more: wouldn't this create a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not** fire a **selector** that calls a **nested method call**.

Selectors are only method names with showing number of arguments as `method:abc:yxa:`

As the statement below:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"[[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] hasFlash]");
```

is calling

```
[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]
```

then

```
[objectReturnedByAbove hasFlash]
```

Comment: I understand. I would be able to by breaking down the strings but then there are better solutions for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: few weeks ago, i need similar kind of thing, i posted and got a lot downvotes and question got removed. You should thank to everyone as your question is still here :D