# Boolean formula in string evaluation

Tags: objective-c

I'm storing a formula `1 && !0 && (0 || 1)` in a `NSString` variable. I need to evaluate this string to a single boolean. Does anyone know of a built in obj-c object for handling this or a 3rd party solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`[NSPredicate parseWithFormat:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithFormat%3a) and [`[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPredicate/evaluateWithObject%3a) could help here.

Comment: I had to reformat my formula string to this "1 == 1 AND NOT 0 == 1 AND ( 0 == 1 OR 1 == 1)" but this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short of parsing it yourself, you won't be able to evaluate an expression like that in Objective-C during runtime since it is not an interpreted language.

Here are just a few (of many) other resources that pretty much echo this:

- [eval in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158036/eval-in-objective-c)
- [Is there something like Matlab's eval statement in Objective-C
  2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116885/is-there-something-like-matlabs-eval-statement-in-objective-c-2-0)
- [“eval” for Objective-C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550897/eval-for-objective-c-code)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651333/evaluate-math-expression-in-string-nsstring) may get you a step closer to what you are trying to achieve.  In any scenario, you will have to parse it yourself.